# Video players for mov files?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, mpmovieplayer

I am using MpMovieplayer to play mov files dynamically(selecting videos from devices) in ios 5 but it is not playing.It shows blackscreen.I also tried directly movie url giving to player but it doesn't work.Is there any player instead of MPMovieplayer to play mov files.Thanks in advance

```
  NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Movie" ofType:@"mov"];
  NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

  NSLog(@"movieURL ----%@",movieURL);
 movieplayer=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];

 if([movieplayer respondsToSelector:@selector(view)])
 {
    movieplayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
    [movieplayer.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:movieplayer.view];
     movieplayer.shouldAutoplay=true;
    [movieplayer play];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"your movie"    ofType:@"mov"];


MPMoviePlayerViewController* tmpMoviePlayViewController=[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];

if (tmpMoviePlayViewController) {

    tmpMoviePlayViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

    [self presentModalViewController:tmpMoviePlayViewController animated:YES];

    tmpMoviePlayViewController.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self

                                             selector:@selector(myMovieViewFinishedCallback:)

                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification

                                               object:tmpMoviePlayViewController];





    [tmpMoviePlayViewController.moviePlayer play];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the AVPlayer class.

MPMoviePlayerController is actually 'derived' from the AVPlayer class so that could make it work.